# Inequality triangle area

Tags: geometry, inequality, contest-math

> Let $ a, b, c $ be the sides of a triangle $ ABC $  and $ k $ be its area. Prove that $ 4k \leq  \min \{ a ^ 2 + b ^ 2, a ^ 2 + c ^ 2, b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 \}$

My thoughts: area of a triangle is $\frac12 ab\sin C$

Comment: $4k = 2ab\sin C \le 2ab \le a^2+b^2$...

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem in the manner you suggest and as shown in the comment i.e.

$$4k=2ab\sin C\le 2ab$$
$$2ab=a^2+b^2-(a-b)^2\le a^2+b^2.$$

The result can also be shown geometrically. This is especially straightforward for a right-angled triangle. If $c$ is the length of the hypotenuse, you can fit four copies of the triangles together inside a square of side $c$.